# IPTABLES REJECT by port error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, iptables, firewall

I am working on a firewall and i have some problems. I open a `SOCKS5` on port, let's say `33333` and if i don't have any rules in IPTABLES it is working. When i apply my rules it is working. Those are my rules :

```
# RULE 0 : Add some headers
*filter

# RULE 1
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s 0/0 -p tcp  --dport 1080:65535  -j REJECT <--- THIS RULE MIGHT BE WRONG
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport ssh -j REJECT

# RULE 13
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 465 -j REJECT

# RULE 2
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --match multiport --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s xxx.xxx.175.220 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s xxx.xxx.175.222 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s xxx.xxx.175.242 --dport ssh -j ACCEPT

# RULE 7
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 15001:25000 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 18420 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp  -s xxx.xxx.35.132/32 --dport 18420 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 23152 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp  -s xxx.xxx.199.34/32 --dport 23152 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 16932 -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp  -s xxx.xxx.255.186/32 --dport 16932 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 19472 -j REJECT

# RULE 8
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp  --match multiport --dports 5000:6000 -j ACCEPT

# RULE 8
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp  -s 127.0.0.1/32 --match multiport --dports 0:65535 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp  -s xxx.xxx.141.110/32 --match multiport --dports 0:65535 -j ACCEPT

# RULE 9
-I OUTPUT -o eth1 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# RULE 11
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s xxx.xxx.163.214 -p tcp  --dport 6000:65535  -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s xxx.xxx.154.8 -p tcp  --dport 6000:65535  -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s xxx.xxx.208.175 -p tcp  --dport 6000:65535  -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s xxx.xxx.232.43 -p tcp  --dport 6000:65535  -j REJECT
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s xxx.xxx.60.239 -p tcp  --dport 6000:65535  -j REJECT

# RULE 13
COMMIT
```

if i run `ifconfig` i get this :

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:0a:89:b0
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.141.110  Bcast:xxx.xxx.141.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4558771351 errors:0 dropped:6351 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5256425350 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:974002772174 (907.1 GiB)  TX bytes:1003703499168 (934.7 GiB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:df900000-df920000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8611035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8611035 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3936947723 (3.6 GiB)  TX bytes:3936947723 (3.6 GiB)
```

if i delete this line

```
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s 0/0 -p tcp  --dport 1080:65535  -j REJECT <--- THIS RULE MIGHT BE WRONG
```

it works, but the rest of the rules don't like i don't have any firewall active, this is  how i developed it. The "funny" thing is that on other servers that have `eth0` instead of `eth1` it is working perfectly.

I also added `-i eth1` after every `-I INPUT` but nothing ...

What is the problem?

On this server i am using `Debian GNU/Linux 7 \n \l` on the others i use `Ubuntu 14`. On this server (server with the problem), i have to use Debian7 ... not my choice.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're missing a "not" somewhere in your first paragraph.  I can't tell which state isn't working.

Comment: what 'not" ?? what do you mean?

Comment: "if i don't have any rules in IPTABLES it is working. When i apply my rules it is working." -- so, that means it's all working, so there's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The connection to port 33333 cannot work because of the very first rule:

```
-I INPUT -i eth1 -s 0/0 -p tcp  --dport 1080:65535  -j REJECT
```

This rule, while accepted by iptables, is malformed. It should probably look like this (the `-s 0/0` is redundant as it matches all packets):

```
-I INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1080:65535 -j REJECT
```

This rule will drop reject packets on all ports from 1080 to 65535. A simple fix would be adding a rule to open the port 33333:

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 33333 -j ACCEPT
```

Anyway, your approach to creating the firewall where you are mixing accepts/rejects on various ports/from various hosts might not be the best one. Usually, the rules in the INPUT table go like this:

- Accept certain packets
- Drop/reject all others

To show a more detailed example:

```
# Accept packets on loopback interface
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# Open certain ports
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports x,y,z -j ACCEPT
...
# Accept packets from established/related connections - to allow packets from locally-originated connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Drop everything else (or REJECT)
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

That makes for a clean and straightforward firewall where only certain ports are open and all others are closed.

Comment: thanks. i observed 2 things 1) if i use `-I` then then `REJECT` must be at the top as possible 2) if i use `-A` then `REJECT` must be to the bottom as possible. i actually solved the problem by putting an `ACCEPT` after `# RULE 7` on that particulary port that i want to let it free, what do you think about all of this?

Comment: `-I` means **insert**, `-A` means **add**. iptables rules are applied in order, so the first matching rule wins. Although adding another `ACCEPT` into your ruleaset works, for clean and easy to understand firewall you should consider rewriting it - first allowing certain packets and then dropping all others is the best approach.

Comment: `first allowing certain packets and then dropping all` -> so what you are saying is the best firewall is to have some `ACCEPT`'s at beginning, and at the bottom some `DROP`'s, right? What should i use, `-I` or `-A` ?

Comment: Yes, to repeat - the cleanest solution is to only allow the packets you want to go through (`ACCEPT`s at the beginning), and then drop ALL other packets (`-A INPUT -j DROP` or `REJECT`). Of course you can use specific REJECTs as well if needed (usually before the `ACCEPT`s), for example if you want to block some IPs. `-I` **inserts** a rule at a specified position, `-A` **adds** a rule at the end of the chain. If you are building the firewall from scratch (e.g. on boot) it's best to use `-A`  - the rules will appear in the order you put them in.